# Redis under asan with jemalloc

Tags: redis, malloc, sanitizer

I am compiling Redis 3.0.6 in 4 different ways:

1. jemalloc
2. libc malloc
3. asan + jemalloc (`-fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer`)
4. asan + libc malloc

Then I run the standard `redis-bench` under all of those binaries. What I don't understand is that scenario `3` has a performance very very close to scenario `1`.

Can someone explain to me how is this possible? I didn't find anything on asan manual that it doesn't support jemalloc or something relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide exact repro-case but my guess is that you

- use GCC
- link to jemalloc using LD_PRELOAD

In that case, jemalloc's allocator will override ASan's interceptors and heap allocations won't be checked (which would explain no slowdown in your run). Instead you should statically link your executable with jemalloc:

```
LDFLAGS += -ljemalloc
```

I think ideally ASan should report a helpful warning when it fails to intercept the heap allocator so you may want to file a bug at their github.